# Why are random new lines appearing when I convert ASCII into hexadecimal?

Tags: c++, encoding, hex, ascii

So I'm writing a C++ program to read in a text file, find the numerical ASCII values of each character and convert it into hexadecimal and then output it to to the screen but I keep getting these random new lines inserted whenever a hexadecimal value ending in 'C' comes up.

[Screenshot of console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE1yj.png)

Here is the code I am using to convert to hexadecimal:

```
std::string HexConvert(char character) {
    char HEX[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
    int ASCII = (int) character;
    if (ASCII > 255 || ASCII < 32) {
        return "20";
    } else {
        std::vector<char> binaryVec = binaryConvert(ASCII);
        std::string binaryVal(binaryVec.begin(), binaryVec.end());
        binaryVal = binaryVal.substr(binaryVal.length() - 8, 8);
        std::string bin1 = binaryVal.substr(0, 4);
        std::string bin2 = binaryVal.substr(4, 4);
        int hex1 = ((bin1[0] - 48)*8) + ((bin1[1] - 48)*4) + ((bin1[2] - 48)*2) + ((bin1[3] - 48)*1);
        int hex2 = ((bin2[0] - 48)*8) + ((bin2[1] - 48)*4) + ((bin2[2] - 48)*2) + ((bin2[3] - 48)*1);
        char hexVal[2] = { HEX[hex1], HEX[hex2] };
        std::string hexValue(hexVal);
        return hexValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.

Answer (score 2):

It's faster to simply scrap the whole thing, and convert `ASCII` to hex the right way, instead of figuring out the bug.

```
std::ostringstream o;

o << std::hex << std::uppercase << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << ASCII;

return o.str();
```

Comment: Will I need any other #includes for this ostringstream?

Comment: You'll need `<sstream>` and `<iomanip>`, don't think anything else is needed. Check your C++ reference manual if there's any doubt.

Comment: Doesn't seem to like std::fill - says it needs 3 arguments but only one given.

Comment: Thanks for that it sorted the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the terminating null byte for a string.

```
char hexVal[3] = { HEX[hex1], HEX[hex2], 0 };
```

Without the terminating null, you were running into undefined behavior; anything could have happened.